# Unable to remove the git objects after sync

Tags: git, gerrit

I have the below git objects which I am not able to remove after the sync completed. Any suggestions as how to remove them?

```
$ cd sync/.git/objects/64

$ rm -rf 536e6093128d396fa5dca21152f3f1dc44abe7
rm: cannot remove `536e6093128d396fa5dca21152f3f1dc44abe7': Permission denied
```

Comment: 1. `ls -la 536e6093128d396fa5dca21152f3f1dc44abe7` 2. `id`

Comment: well..
-bash-4.1$ ls -la 536e6093128d396fa5dca21152f3f1dc44abe7
-r--r--r-- 1 sam alpha 848 Dec 12 12:03 536e6093128d396fa5dca21152f3f1dc44abe7

Comment: its 444 i know..but i cannot continue without deleting it...:(

Comment: 2. `id` 3. `ls -la .` line for `.`

Comment: and please add the outputs to your question. don't hide relevant information in comments.

Comment: my bad..i just moved the directory..which had these contents.. and it worked smooth

Answer (score 0):

check file access rights for your user and check ACL